# Making Konsole to be login shell by default

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, konsole

I don't know why there are "login" and "non-login" shells in the first place, and i'm not very eager to know.

The fact is that the [RVM](http://rvm.io/) and [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) software that i use frequently require login shells, and Konsole starts a non-login shell.

This forces me to submit a  `bash -l` command every time i start a Konsole.

How do i make Konsole start in login shell mode by default?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/132276/configure-gnome-terminal-to-start-bash-as-a-login-shell-doesnt-read-bashrc

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, well, your link suggest to enable login shell in Gnome Shell options. Unfortunately, Konsole does not have such an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The Konsole Handbook:](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/konsole/konsole.pdf)

> Konsole doesn’t provide convenience for running login shell, because
>   developers don’t like the idea of running login shell in a terminal
>   emulator.
>
> Of course, users still can run login shell in Konsole if they really
>   need to. Edit the profile in use and modify its command to the form of
>   starting a login shell explicitly, such as "bash -l" and "zsh -l".

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I was surprised that my .zprofile wasn't being run in Konsole. I wonder whether it's true that "developers don't like the idea of running login shell in a terminal emulator"?

Comment: Probably because the login shell is supposed to be the one that is run when you login, not every time you open a new terminal. [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)

Comment: I don't by the idea of not running the login shell in new tabs being what MOST developer don't want.  I did want to add that the `command` option is on the General page of the settings dialog.

Comment: yea, kde Konsole - right click -> Edit Current Profile -> General -> Command : ```/bin/bash -l```

Comment: @Alexey thanks, it works