# How can I find where certain bash function is defined?

Tags: bash, functions

There are many functions that can be used in Bash shell. Their definitions can be listed by `set`, but how to find in which files certain user defined functions are defined?

Comment: Look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turn on debugging. From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

> #### extdebug
>
> If set at shell invocation, or in a shell startup file, arrange to
>   execute the debugger profile before the shell starts, identical to the
>   `--debugger` option. If set after invocation, behavior intended for
>   use by debuggers is enabled:
>
> - The `-F` option to the `declare` builtin (see [Bash Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)) displays the source file name and line number corresponding to each
>     function name supplied as an argument.

Example:

```
$ bash --debugger
$ declare -Ff quote
quote 143 /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

And indeed:

```
$ nl -ba /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion | sed -n 143,150p
   143  quote()
   144  {
   145      local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}
   146      printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
   147  }
   148
   149  # @see _quote_readline_by_ref()
   150  quote_readline()
```

Comment: This is a great and simple solution. As for your example, it is not even needed to start a new shell: `shopt -s extdebug; declare -Ff quote; shopt -u extdebug`.

Comment: @jarno ah, well, contrary to my name, I use zsh. That's why I started a new shell. :D

Comment: Is there a _similar_ method to find **alias** declaration locations?

Comment: @fedon my convoluted and complicated approach below should work.

Comment: You could make this a function like this: `find_function()( shopt -s extdebug; declare -F "$@"; )`. With the parens on the function body, it gets executed in a subshell and the change to shopts doesn't affect the caller. And the `-f` doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 18):

This is actually more complicated than it appears at first. Which files are read by your shell depends on [what type of shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/879400/85695) you are currently running. Whether it is interactive or not, whether it is a login or a non-login shell and what combination of the above. To search through all the default files that can be read by the different shells, you can do (change `$functionName` to the actual name of the function you are looking for):

```
grep "$functionName" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash.login \
                     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

If that doesn't work, you may be calling a non-default file using `.` or its alias `source`. To find such cases, run:

```
grep -P '(^|\s)(\.|source)\s+' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile \
                               ~/.bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc \
                               /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

That probably needs some explanation. The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) which let us use some fancier regex syntax. Specifically:

- `(^|\s)`: match either the beginning of a line (`^`) or whitespace (`\s`).
- `(\.|source)\s+` : match either a literal `.` character (`\.`) or the word `source`, but only if they are followed by one or more whitespace characters.

Here's what that gives me on my system:

```
$ grep -P '(^|\s)(\.|source)\s+' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile \
>                                ~/.bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc \
>                                /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
/home/terdon/.bashrc:   . /etc/bashrc
/home/terdon/.bashrc:   . /etc/bash_completion
/home/terdon/.bashrc:. $HOME/scripts/git-prompt.sh
/home/terdon/.bashrc:#  echo -n "$n : "; grep "^CA"  $n |perl -e 'my ($a,$c)=0; while(<>){$c++;next if /cellular_component_unknown/; next if /biological_process/; $a++} print "$a Classes of $c annotated (" . $a*100/$c . ")\n"' 
/etc/bash.bashrc:[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
/etc/profile:       test -r "$profile" && . "$profile"
/etc/profile:   . /etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/locale.conf"
/etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . "$HOME/.config/locale.conf"
/etc/profile.d/locale.sh:    . /etc/locale.conf
/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh:        . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh:        . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh:        . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh:        . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh:        . /usr/bin/byobu-launch
```

As you can see, however, this will print the entire matched line. What we are really interested in is the list of file names called, not the line that is calling them. You can get those with this, more complicated, regex:

```
grep -hPo '(^|\s)(\.|source)\s+\K\S+' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile \
                                      ~/.bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
                                      /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                                      /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

The `-h` flag suppresses the printing of the file names where a match was found, which `grep` does by default when told to search through multiple files. The `-o` means "only print the matching portion of the line". The extra stuff added to the regex are:

- `\K` : ignore anything matched up to this point. This is a PCRE trick that lets you use a complex regex to find your match but not include that matched portion when using grep's `-o` flag.

On my system, the above command will return:

```
$ grep -hPo '(^|\s)(\.|source)\s+\K\S+' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile \
>                                       ~/.bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
>                                       /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
>                                       /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
/etc/bashrc
/etc/bash_completion
$HOME/scripts/git-prompt.sh
$a*100/$c
")\n"'
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
"$profile"
/etc/bash.bashrc
"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/locale.conf"
"$HOME/.config/locale.conf"
/etc/locale.conf
/usr/bin/byobu-launch
/usr/bin/byobu-launch
/usr/bin/byobu-launch
/usr/bin/byobu-launch
/usr/bin/byobu-launch
```

Note that I happen to have a use of `.` followed by a space which is *not* used for sourcing but that's because I have an alias that is calling another language, not bash. That's what gives the weird `$a*100/$c` and `")\n"'` in the output above. But that can be ignored.

Finally, here's how to put all of that together and search for a function name in all default files *and* all files your default files are sourcing:

```
grep_function(){
  target="$@"
  files=( ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash.login 
         ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile 
         /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment)
    while IFS= read -r file; do
      files+=( "$file" )
    done < <(grep -hPo '(^|\s)(\.|source)\s+\K\S+'  "${files[@]}" 2>/dev/null)
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
      ## The tilde of ~/ can break this
      file=$(sed 's|~/|'"$HOME"'/|g' <<<"$file")
      if [[ -e $file ]]; then
        grep -H "$target" -- "$file"
      fi
    done
}
```

Add those lines to your `~/.bashrc` and you can then run (I am using `fooBar` as an example function name):

```
grep_function fooBar
```

For example, if I have this line in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
. ~/a
```

And the file `~/a` is:

```
$ cat ~/a
fooBar(){
  echo foo
}
```

I should find it with:

```
$ grep_function fooBar
/home/terdon/a:fooBar(){
```

Comment: Your solution is a great educational scripting example, but I find bashity mcbashface's solution simpler.

Comment: @jarno and it is much, much simpler! :)

Comment: Arrays support `+=`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble they do? You mean other than `array+="foo"` appending the string `foo` to the 1st element of the array?

Comment: Try `array+=(foo)`—works in my bash

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks! I didn't know bash arrays supported that notation!

Answer (score 2):

The *usual* per-user dotfile `bash` reads is `~/.bashrc`. However, it may very well source other files, I for instance like to keep aliases and functions in separate files called `~/.bash_aliases` and `~/.bash_functions`, which makes finding them much easier. You can search the `.bashrc` for `source` commands with:

```bsh
grep -E '(^\s*|\s)(\.|source)\s' /home/USERNAME/.bashrc
```

Once you have the list of user-created files you can search them and the user’s `.bashrc` with a single `grep` call, e.g. for function `foo` for my setup:

```bsh
grep foo /home/USERNAME/.bash{rc,_aliases,_functions}
```

Comment: This is not a satisfactory answer. There are a awful lot of functions that are not set by the end user. The questions obviously asks for how to find them. And this is of course a far more interesting use case than finding the functions you have created yourself, which you should normally find again in seconds if you're a bit organized

Comment: @Atralb The question explicitly asks for “user defined functions”.