# Putty does not start .bashrc

Tags: bash, bashrc

When I connect to my Ubuntu system remotely, `.bashrc` is not getting loaded. I know this because lines at the end of `.bashrc` simply do not run, though they do if I manually dotsource after logging in with `. .bashrc`. I looked in `/etc/skel` and checked `.profile` etc, and I *also* see the loader lines for `.bashrc` in the users `/home/myuser/.profile`. Here are the lines in `/home/myuser/.profile` (and I am logging into the system with `myuser` from Putty.exe from a remote Windows host). Why does `.bashrc` not load as when I log into the system from Putty, `/home/myuser/.profile` should be loading right?

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: The files in `/etc/skel` are just *template files* - what actually matters are the remote user account's own `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_login` (which takes priority if it exists)

Comment: oh, then I really don't understand ... From putty on Windows, I point at the Ubuntu host IP and log in as `myuser` which is a user that exists on the Ubuntu box. As far as I'm concerned, there is no remote user, I'm just logging in with the credentials of the local user `myuser` right? So, I go to `/home/myuser` and in `~/.profile` the lines that I put in my original question are there. I only mentioned `/etc/skel` as I checked there also, but the lines that I put above are in `/home/myuser/.profile`. I was not clear in my question and I've updated that. Still, `.bashrc` does not load.

Comment: By any chance, do the files `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exist? Because if they exist, `~/.profile` is not read.

Comment: You got it @raj, thanks.  Somehow a zero-length `.bash_profile` appeared in that folder. Wow, the convoluted ways that bash uses various types of profile files is ever-bizarre and confusing ... 

Comment: @raj make it an answer >:-D

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu doesn't run `.bashrc`. With Ubuntu, `gnome-terminal` does not normally run as a [login shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879364/differentiate-interactive-login-and-non-interactive-non-login-shell), so `.bashrc` should be run directly.

For login shells (like the virtual terminals), normally the file `~/.profile` is run, unless you have either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`, but they are not there by default. By default, Ubuntu uses only `.profile`.