# problem bashrc file colored terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, bashrc, syntax

I have a problem with my terminal in Ubuntu server 20.04.
I would like to color the syntax in my terminal, but after I restart the server, it's back to the normal uncolored syntax. I edited `.bashrc` and uncommented this line:

```
force_color_promp=yes
```

I then and restarted `.bashrc` with the command `source .bashrc`, but as I wrote earlier, after restart it returns to the previous non colored syntax.

I don't use ssh to connect to the server. I'm working on it through the console, and I don't have a `.bash_login` file. I am trying to find a different configuration file.

Comment: How are you running your Ubuntu Server? Via the console or via ssh or some other way? I suspect that .bashrc is not involved or not last when setting the environment for your terminal. So you should identify some other configuration file and make the modification there.

Comment: Are you using a login shell or an interactive non-login shell (i.e. does `echo $0` say `-bash` or just `bash`?) Do you have a `~/.bash_login` file? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: I don't use ssh to connect to the server. Im works in it through the console I don't have a .bash_login file. I am trying to find a different configuration file

Comment: I don't see a reason to use `sudo` here at all.

Comment: @Dany, I'm testing an Ubuntu Kinetic Server (to be released as 22.10), and after `Force_color_prompt=yes` and saving it, there is a coloured prompt for me after reboot. I'm not sure about 20.04 LTS, but something seems to be different. You can check your `~.profile` and `/etc/profile`. Maybe there is a problem with the ownership of your `~/.bashrc` because you used sudo with it. Please check that, as hinted by mook765.

Comment: @sudodus problem solved i found a problem, the files .bash_logout .profile were empty, thanks for your help and good intentions

Comment: @Dany, Congratulations :-) Please tell us about your solution, it can help other users with the same or a similar problem.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks :) , I've already added an answer to the my question

Comment: @Dany, Great description :-) However, it would be even better if you create an 'answer' and put your solution steps there. After a couple of days you can 'accept' it (click on the tick mark). That will indicate that your question has an accepted solution (and would be worthwhile to visit for other users :-)

Comment: Yes, please don't post solutions as part of the question. I have deleted your solution because i) it was posted as part of the question and ii) it is a very, very bad solution! NEVER edit your user's configuration files with `sudo`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `.bashrc` is not relevant to your case. When you log into your server from the console, you are starting an interactive login shell and that kind of shell ignores `~/.bashrc` and instead reads `~/.profile`.

So, to make the changes you want persistent, you need to make your edits in `~/.profile` and not `~/.bashrc`. See here for a more in-depth explanation of what files are read in what types of shell:

- [Why are scripts in /etc/profile.d/ being ignored (system-wide bash aliases)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/438150/85695)
- [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/q/879364/85695)
- [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/q/183870/151431)