# What is an example use for a non-interactive login shell?

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh

I understand it is extremely rare and the concept, but can't think of a use for it. I do have an idea that we may want to execute a script that has a command to login to a server through ssh, is that something that needs to be done at times and is it an example of where a non-interactive login shell is useful?

Comment: A non-interactive logon shell is used for `cron`, `at`, `batch` jobs, among other tasks. "Non-interactive" means the process doesn't have a human (or `expect`) attached.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879364/differentiate-interactive-login-and-non-interactive-non-login-shell) (the title is a bit deceptive because the actual question covers all four combinations)

Comment: About 5-10 years ago, LightDM would run a non-interactive login shell to start your GUI session (so it would source `/etc/profile`, etc. and set environment variables and such from there) - that's to say, during that time, non-interactive login shells were _incredibly_ common, if unnoticed. Now GDM is the default and GDM doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Study the Unix way commands are run: the existing (login) shell is forked (duplicated), and the command is execed. If the forked shell runs another shell, that shell is non-interactive.
Type in the command"

```
$ echo "$-  'i' indicates interactive"
himBHs  'i' indicates interactive
```

Now put the above line in a file (foo) and run

```
bash foo
hB  'i' indicates interactive
```

No "i", so being run in a non interactive shell.
Make foo executable and try again"

```
chmod +x foo
./foo
hB  'i' indicates interactive
```

Again no "i"
Unless you force things with:

```
bash -i foo
himBH  'i' indicates interactive
```

Then you again see the "i"