# enviroment variables are not loaded

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, environment-variables, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator to manage my C++ codes on xubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have a bunch of environment variables defined in .bashrc_vars that are loaded in .bashrc. These variables are required for building my application and I need Qt Creator to load them on start up.

If I start Qt Creator from terminal, the variables are loaded but when I click on the icon they don't. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer you can find here...
[/etc/profile not being sourced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced)

So you need define your vars in ~/.profile and make sure that your login shell read that file. For instance gnome-terminal does read ~/.profile at start up.