# Why are scripts in /etc/profile.d/ being ignored (system-wide bash aliases)?

Tags: bash, login, .profile

I'm new to Ubuntu.  I'm running 13.10 Desktop.

I wanted to set some system wide aliases and a custom prompt for bash.  I found this article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Following the advice in this article, I created /etc/profile.d/profile_local.sh.  It is owned by root and has permissions of 644 just like the other scripts there:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/profile.d# ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 23 08:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 135 root root 12288 Mar 23 09:15 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   660 Oct 23  2012 bash_completion.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3317 Mar 23 07:36 profile_local.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1947 Nov 23 00:57 vte.sh
```

I have further confirmed that /etc/profile calls /etc/profile.d.  It contains this code block:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Upon login, it does not appear that the custom script, profile_local.sh I created gets sourced.  However if after login I 'source /etc.profile.d/profile_local.sh', I get the expected behavior, my custom aliases, and custom prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Contents of script 'profile_local.sh':

```
# 3/23/14 - Copied from Gentoo /etc/bash/bashrc
# Placed in /etc/profile.d as described at:
# https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

# This file is sourced by all *interactive* bash shells on startup,
# including some apparently interactive shells such as scp and rcp
# that can't tolerate any output.  So make sure this doesn't display
# anything or bad things will happen !


# Test for an interactive shell.  There is no need to set anything
# past this point for scp and rcp, and it's important to refrain from
# outputting anything in those cases.
if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
        # Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
        return
fi

# Bash won't get SIGWINCH if another process is in the foreground.
# Enable checkwinsize so that bash will check the terminal size when
# it regains control.  #65623
# http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/FAQ (E11)
shopt -s checkwinsize

# Enable history appending instead of overwriting.  #139609
shopt -s histappend

# Change the window title of X terminals 
case ${TERM} in
        xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm|aterm|kterm|gnome*|interix)
                PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
                ;;
        screen)
                PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}\033\\"'
                ;;
esac

use_color=false

# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
# dircolors --print-database uses its own built-in database
# instead of using /etc/DIR_COLORS.  Try to use the external file
# first to take advantage of user additions.  Use internal bash
# globbing instead of external grep binary.
safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
        && type -P dircolors >/dev/null \
        && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true

if ${use_color} ; then
        # Enable colors for ls, etc.  Prefer ~/.dir_colors #64489
        if type -P dircolors >/dev/null ; then
                if [[ -f ~/.dir_colors ]] ; then
                        eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)
                elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
                        eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
                fi
        fi

        if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
                PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
        else
                PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
        fi

        alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
else
        if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
                # show root@ when we don't have colors
                PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
        else
                PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
        fi
fi

# Try to keep environment pollution down, EPA loves us.
unset use_color safe_term match_lhs

TZ="PST8PDT"

alias ll='ls -la'
alias dig='dig +search'
alias dir='ls -ba'

alias edit="ee"
alias ss="ps -aux"
alias dot='ls .[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
alias news="xterm -g 80x45 -e trn -e -S1 -N &"

alias more="less"
alias c="clear"
alias m="more"
alias j="jobs"

# common misspellings
alias mroe=more
alias pdw=pwd
```

Comment: It could be timing. What exactly are you calling? Sometimes the system isn't ready yet and nothing will happen on the call.

Comment: Hi Mr. Lee.  Thanks for your reply.  I'm trying to get the same prompt and aliases I am used to on Gentoo systems I have.  This is the contents of my script:

-- Apparently comments are limited in length.  I'll get the script posted as soon as I figure out how.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I've put `<code> </code>` around the code but the formatting isn't working.  Not sure how to fix.

Comment: Dunno if this applies but, I think all .sh files need `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

Comment: I thought about that but neither of the other two files in there (which I did not create) have that.  I'm assuming not since the files here are called by /etc/profile.

However I did try adding and tested.  No change.

Comment: No, it's not executable but neither are the other two scripts.  However I changed it and tried again.  Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried [bash.bashrc](http://superuser.com/questions/49562/whats-the-difference-between-etc-bash-bashrc-and-bashrc-which-one-should-i) Aliases are usually placed in bashrc. Systemwise aliases are placed in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: This has nothing to do with adding `.sh`, it is irrelevant and anyway the files in `profile.d` are sourced, not executed which is slightly different and does not require the file to be executable. The issue here is that `profile` &co are not read by non-login scripts.

Comment: @Mr. Lee. Funny you mention that.  I was just checking it.  I've found that I'm a bit mistaken.  /etc/profile.d/profile_local.sh must be called as I do see my custom aliases but not my custom PS1.

I found this line in /etc/bash.bashrc:

`# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`

But even after commenting out, I still don't get my custom PS1.

So there is something about the script that doesn't set PS1 when called upon login but works if sourced after login.

Comment: Drew, read my answer. The profile files are ignored by non-login shells but Ubuntu's default GUI login will read some of them. Just use `.bashrc` and all your problems will go away. There is also a question of precedence, if one of the files that are read subsequently also sets PS1, then the previous value will be discarded. Anyway, seriously, don't touch the filers in `/etc`, play with the ones in your home dir and use `.bashrc` not profile.

Comment: @terdon, thank you for your reply.  I think I am using a login shell.  I am using SecureCRT from a Windows 7 box to connect to the Ubuntu machine.  I'm logging in as myself and authenticating using a key.  Thus this would be a login shell, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be a login shell (that's the kind if thing you should include in your question next time). However, most systems have default `.profile` files in your home and the settings there will overwrite anything you do in `/etc/profile`. Basically _never_ touch `/etc` unless you know what you're doing. That's what the user-specific files are for. Also, please [edit] your question and explain exactly how you are connecting, that changes everything.

Comment: Thank you all.  @terdon's clue of "precedence" and suggestion of .bashrc led me to check my home directory.  I found a .bashrc file there that sets PS1 and thus was overwriting the one I specified in /etc/profile.d.

Comment: Please don't do this using `/etc/profile.d` that is a really bad idea and will affect all users of the system. Just include the commands from `profile_local.sh` in your `~/.profile` or simply source the script by adding this line to your `~/.profile` : `. /path/to/profile_local.sh`. (the `.` means `source`, it will read the file you give it and run the commands it finds there).

Comment: I understand.  However I started with /etc/profile.d precisely because I wanted to affect all users. :)  Now while this particular machine will only be accessed by me, I will likely have a few different accounts on it and just wanted to avoid having to set up separate customizations for each account.  Not that it would be a big deal but that's why I started with /etc/profile.d.  But now that I know that Ubuntu makes a default ./bashrc for each user anyway, I just as well add my changes there.

Thanks for your detailed explanation of how it all works.  It is very helpful.

Comment: I "second" what @terdon said. Plus-plus-plus, in any scripts that you want to have run automatically on each login, never-never-never end your script with an 'exit' command as that will log you out. If you were silly enough (like I was) to link that script in /etc/profile.d/ you'll find that you're never able to get a command prompt---you'll be logged out as soon as your script run. Instead, remove the 'exit' command from your script and then do as terdon suggested: add a line at the very bottom of your ~/.profile file that runs the command. This way, if you're only affecting 1 user account.

Comment: To wrap up what I was just saying, do not place 'exit' in any script within /etc/profile.d/. The way I managed to resolve this was to use Putty psftp to connect to the server, manually delete the file from my ~/.bin/ folder... and I was able to successfully log in.

Comment: .bashrc is not the place to set paths. bashrc is for interactive non login shells

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, you need to understand a little background information about how shells (bash in this case) are run.

- When you open a terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal` for example), you are executing what is known as an *interactive, non-login* shell.
- When you log into your machine from the command line, via `ssh`, or run a command such as `su - username`, you are running an *interactive login* shell.
- When you log in graphically, you are running something completely different, the details will depend on your system and graphical environment but in general it is the *graphical shell* that deals with your login. While many graphical shells (including the Ubuntu default) will read `/etc/profile` not all of them do.
- Finally, when you run a shell script, it is run in a *non-interactive, non-login shell*.

Now, the files that bash will read when launched depend on the type of shell it is running as. The following is an excerpt of the INVOCATION section of `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> When  bash is invoked as an **interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.  After reading
>     that file, it looks for **~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>    in  that order**, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>    shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an **interactive shell** that is **not a login shell**  is  started,  bash
>   reads  and  executes  commands  from **/etc/bash.bashrc** and **~/.bashrc**, if
>   these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the  --norc  option.
>   The  --rcfile  file option will force bash to read and execute commands
>   from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

What all this means is that you are editing the wrong file. You can test this by dropping to a virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (return to the GUI with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, or <kbd>F8</kbd> depending on your setup)  and logging in there. You will see that your prompt and aliases are available.

So, in order to have the setting you want applied to non-login shells, the type you get each time you open a terminal, you should make your changes to `~/.bashrc` instead. Alternatively, you can also place your aliases in the file `~/.bash_aliases` (however, note that this is an Ubuntu feature and you should not expect it to work on other distributions).

For more details on which file should be used for what, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/183956/151431).

---

**NOTES:**

- Debian (and by extension Ubuntu) also has the default `~/.profile` source `~/.bashrc`. This means that any changes you make to `~/.bashrc` will also be inherited by login shells but i) this is not the case in all Linux/Unix machines and ii) the inverse is not true which is why you should generally always work with `~/.bashrc` &co rather than `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`.
- Also, a general note on usage, changes made to the configuration files in `/etc` will affect *all* users. This is usually not what you want to do and should be avoided. You should always use the equivalent files in your home directory (`~/`).
- The various configuration files are read sequentially. Specifically, for login shells, the order is:

  ```
  /etc/profile -> /etc/profile.d/* (in alphabetical order) -> ~/.bash_profile -> ~/.bash_login -> ~/.profile
  ```

  This means that any setting in `~/.profile` will overwrite anything set in the previous files.

Comment: According to this post http://howtolamp.com/articles/difference-between-login-and-non-login-shell/, you can also run `echo $0` from a terminal and if the output is prefixed with a "-" then you are in a login shell.

Comment: @stackoverflower not on my system. That works for a remote, interactive login shell. Doesn't seem to when running `bash -l`. In any case, why is that relevant? The question is not about how to check what type of shell you're running.

Comment: magnificant post, wonder why it didn't show up on google when I had the same problem

Comment: @stackoverflower If `"$0"` expands to something that starts with `-`, then you know you have a login shell. But the converse is not true: the absence of `-` doesn't ensure you're not in a login shell. Most common ways of starting login shells do give you a leading `-`, but not all. `man bash` tells us *"A **login shell** is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`,  or one started with the `--login` option."* (`-l` is the short form of `--login`; [they're equivalent](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash).) In Bash you can run `shopt login_shell` to check.

Answer (score 12):

in Debian for Terminal session I solved this problem for all user so:

added to

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

block

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

from

```
/etc/profile
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: from https://askubuntu.com/a/40313/236325 , seems a long standing bug on Ubuntu

Comment: this is not a coincidence that there is a separation between bashrc and profile scripts. doing this, you alter the intended behavior....

Comment: This is clever however it is another workaround forcing bash config files to source profile files, which is technically a loop (profile should be loaded first). If you are going to modify `bash.bashrc` you might as well just add your scripts directly to that file... unless you have a large amount of profile scripts you are sourcing? See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/103740/935172

Comment: @kisp `doing this, you alter the intended behavior` ... which is?

Comment: Does this mean that when I'm starting a login shell, the files at /etc/profile.d will be loaded twice?

Comment: @jgomo3 Yes - It will. To test this theory, I added "mkdir -p /test; sleep 1; touch /test/$(whoami)-$(date +"%s")" and any time I open a shell, interactive or not, two files will be created with on second separating them. Whether this is a bad thing or not I guess depends on what you have in your profile.d scripts and if they are idempotent or not.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this path:

- Open Edit -> Preferences
- In the first tab "General", under label "Command", enable "Run command as login shell"

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, especially for settings like the history settings `HISTSIZE`, `HISTFILESIZE`, `HISTCONTROL`, and `PS1` is that the files are being loaded, but settings are overwritten in another file that is source later, with the most likely culprit being `~/.bashrc`. (I have a default set of settings for our servers, like a prompt that is red for root to warn the user and large histories with timestamps)

The default Ubuntu `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` sets several settings, which might have made sense to set from somewhere where it would not override settings set by the system owner from `/etc/profile.d` (Like `/etc/bash.bashrc`) (If a user edits their `.bashrc`, it is fine to overwrite settings, the system default files are more annoying)

Answer (score -1):

VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

Okay so everyone has assumed that the person here doesn't want /etc/profile.d/somefile.sh for all users, but in my case that's exactly what I wanted.

So actually as it turns out with Ubuntu if you use this and you want it to take effect in your graphical shell, all you have to do is set the file and then logout and back in again. All your consoles or anything you launch whether it be xterm type or console type (Or dropping to the shell) will now have that file sourced.

No need to use .bashrc etc for all users.  Sorry this just wasn't clear in above answer. Everything they said is true but in reality its mostly not true as everything the windows manager launches will inherit these settings so just re-login and solve your issue and don't bother with .bashrc etc if your intention is to apply it to all users.

Comment: My problem is exactly that this *does not* happen in the terminal run under the graphical user interface; neither in Ubuntu 16.04.3 or 18.04.