# Cannot find location of permanent aliases.

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

A couple of months ago, I made a few permanent aliases for my bash shell on Ubuntu 14.04. They are actively making my life easier, and I would like to add a couple more to the list, but I cannot find them. My `.bashrc` file does not actually contain any aliases, just the lines about running `~/.bash_aliases` if it exists. And my `~/.bash_aliases` file is completely blank.

Comment: Also How you made permanent aliases (by editing which file) a couple of month ago?

Answer (score 1):

Run `man bash` to see what files `bash` may be looking at. 
They include `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`,
and, if you went privileged, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`. 
Or you could pick a word or a sequence of words from one of your existing aliases
(for example, `qwerty aardvark42`), and do

```
grep "qwerty aardvark42" ~/.*
grep "qwerty aardvark42" /etc/*
```

Comment: None of `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` will be relevant here. Those are only read by login shells, not the normal interactive ones you run when using a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Bash [reads one of two sets of files](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) depending on how it was invoked. In your case, since you are almost certainly running interactive, non login shells, the possible locations of your aliases are:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_aliases
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Your aliases should be in one of those files. For next time, you can add this function to your `~/.bashrc` which lets you easily look through all the files where a variable or an alias or similar might be found. This will work for all types of (bash) shell:

```
grep_bash(){
    grep -H "$@" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases \
        /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
}
```

You can then search all those files for any given string by running

```
grep_bash foo
```

Answer (score -3):

The file `/etc/skel/.bashrc` contains the original .bashrc

Comment: How you will find location of permanent aliases by knowing this fact?

Comment: The aliases are inside the file.

Comment: What make you to be sure about this?

Comment: That file is only used when creating a new user to copy their default `.bashrc` file. It does not affect any running shells at all.