# Changing the value of $HOME in .bashrc

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, bashrc

First of all a bit of background. I apologise in advance for the misuse of terminology. Please correct me where necessary.

For my work I am going to be running simulations remotely via ssh on several ubuntu machines. These machines are in a network and my account is linked across all of them, ie. `$HOME` is `/home/links/Ogaday` and is mirrored across each machine. So I make a directory on one machine in that folder, and it appears in another machine (this is a case where I don't know how to use the correct terms). There is also local memory on each machine, accessible by each user on that machine, called `/scratch/`. I will make a directory in `/scratch/` to do my actual work in, because I don't think I have enough memory on my account to run the simulations in $HOME, and it will be faster because it's all local, I assume.

Now, there is software installed on those machines that I need to use, and it is installed in directories that I have no write access to (`/usr/local/software/`). However, that software has a bash script that sets environment variables. I'm supposed to append the bash script (`source /usr/local/software/etc/bashrc`) to `$HOME/.bashrc` in order to set the necessary environment variables. Pretty standard so far, this sets everything up for this software to run when I log in, correct? Now, I think that the software on these computers hasn't been configured properly, because the `.../etc/bashrc` is supposed to set a variable called `$SOFTWARE_INST_DIR`, the install directory. By default, this is `$HOME/software`, and it is necessary to change that bashrc file so that it instead sets it to `/usr/local/software`. Of course, I don't have write access to to `.../etc/bashrc`. There are other similar issues, this is just the thing that fails first.

As a fix, I copied that file into `$HOME/software-etc/bashrc` and appended `source $HOME/software-etc/bashrc` to `$HOME/.bashrc` instead of appending `source /usr/local/software/etc/bashrc`, so that I can edit the variables it assigns. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this? I thought another solution would be to, instead of copying the bashrc file from the software install location, appending `export $HOME=/scratch/ogaday` to .bashrc, which I assume would reassign my home directory to scratch. Am I correct? Is this dangerous? I wouldn't really be using these machines for anything else except running long simulations on them.

ps: The final solution would be to ask the IT guys to look into it I guess! I'd rather do a quick fix though if it's possible.

Comment: Just `HOME=/scratch/ogaday`. No `export` and no `$` when assigning variables.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I just started reading this file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables. I see the distinction now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with copying the rc file somewhere else. That said, while you can indeed change your `$HOME` by adding `HOME=/foo` to one of the files read on startup (`~/.profile`, for example), that is really not a good idea. `HOME` is used by many things, not just your scripts and there's no reason to change it since that can have unintended consequences.

For example, the default configuration files for a variety of programs, including your shell, are stored in `$HOME`. If you change that, your settings will be lost.

Now, if I understand correctly, your main objective here is to have `$HOME/software` point to `/usr/local/software`. Instead of copying files around, the simplest solution would be to make `$HOME/software` a link pointing to `/usr/local/software`.

1. Rename `$HOME/software` (if it already exists):

   ```
   mv $HOME/software $HOME/software.old
   ```
2. Make a link called `$HOME/software` that points to `/usr/local/software`:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/software $HOME/software
   ```

Now, anything looking for `$HOME/software` will actually find `/usr/local/software` instead.

Similarly, in order to do your work locally on each machine, create the directory in `/scratch` and then link it to your `$HOME`:

```
mkdir /scratch/ogaday
ln -s /scratch/ogaday $HOME/work
```

Now, everything you do in `$HOME/work` will actually happen in `/scratch/ogaday`.

Finally, bear in mind that there are different types of shell. When you log in via `ssh`, you are running an interactive login shell and, on many systems, `$HOME/.bashrc` is ignored by those shells. While Ubuntu specifically does also read `$HOME/.bashrc`, for such shells, many other distributions don't. Therefore, it is safer to use `$HOME/.profile` and not `$HOME/.bashrc` to set environment variables. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) for an explanation of what files are read when.

Comment: This looks great. I didn't redefine $HOME in the end, because I thought it might be fishy. One question though, the work I do in ```$HOME/work``` which is actually happening on scratch, will that be visible on other machines on the network? Because ```$HOME``` is synced across all these computers (I don't actually know where the data there is hosted, on a central sever?), so would that link be local? Synced as well? Copying the bashrc file locally has worked for now, but I think your solution is definitely the proper way to do it.

Comment: @Ogaday the link will appear on all computers but it will point to each computers respective `/scratch/ogaday` directory (if present). So, if you work on machine2, machine2 won't see it.  By the way, if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I definitely will, that sounds perfect, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ugh, last comment should read "if you work on machine1, machine2 won't see it", of course.

Comment: That's how I read it anyway hah.