# stderr of terminal in red, even with sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, gnome-terminal, stdout

I am trying to make a working example for `logrotate`, and to help me through this I figured it was a good idea to turn `stderr` to red.

Through some reading, I came upon [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred), which I meant to adopt.  I downloaded it, make'd it and it works nicely for the user.

The red formatting however is lost when the command is summoned through `sudo`.  Specifically, red formatting is visible with this command:

```
$ /usr/games/cowsay -f fudge Yo
cowsay: Could not find fudge cowfile!
```

but not with this command:

```
$ sudo /usr/games/cowsay -f fudge Yo
cowsay: Could not find fudge cowfile!
```

I have tried editing `/root/.bashrc` to contain:

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/home/user/path/to/stderred/build/libstderred.so${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"
```

but that apparently does not make it work.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/715500/stderr-of-terminal-in-red-when-redirect-12-is-used .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `sudo command` runs `command` in its own subshell, started by `root`. This means that your `~/.bashrc` file is ignored. It also means that any environment variables defined in the parent shell (such as the `LD_PRELOAD` you are setting in `~/.bashrc`) are not passed to the `sudo` shell. This is explained in `man sudoers`:

> By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to
>   be  executed with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux
>   systems  without PAM), **the environment is initialized with the
>   contents of the  /etc/environment file**.  The new environment contains
>   the TERM, PATH,  HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_*
>   variables **in addition to variables from the invoking process
>   permitted by the env_check  and env_keep options**.  This is effectively
>   a whitelist for environment  variables.

I couldn't get the `env_keep` option to work here, I don't know why. The best way I could find of passing the variable to `sudo` is to create a file (for example `/path/to/foo`) with this line:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/home/terdon/Setups/stderred/build/libstderred.so"
```

Then, run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

```
Defaults        env_file="/path/to/foo"
```

That will cause `sudo` to read `/path/to/foo` and add any variable definitions there to its environment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these options a shot.  Did you mean: _(such as the `LD_PRELOAD` you are setting in `/root/.bashrc)`_?

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.10, I get the error `>>> /etc/sudoers: erreur de syntaxe near line 13 <<<` when quitting and saving after the call to `sudo visudo`

Comment: @Tfb9 i) no, I meant `~/.bashrc` which is where you were setting it. That shell (normal user) then calls `sudo` and the `sudo` doesn't inherit the variable. ii) Bon, t'as un erreur sur la ligne 13 donc. iii) you're welcome :)

Comment: i) Understood - but why didn't my edition of /root/.bashrc have any effect? ii) The line 13 error was exactly where I had added the env_keep line. iv) Seems like option 1 (ugliest) is not acceptable - I'm running into scary issues with a script of mine from .bashrc (a script that uses a pipe to `w3m`, which seems to go in error with this setup); symptoms are that for user on ssh, all text is red (even commands I type in) and in VNC I wasn't able to start a new gnome-terminal by clicking the icon. I am back at square I

Comment: @Tfb9 i) See updated answer, I found a clean way of doing it! ii) root's `.bashrc` is not read by `sudo`. `.bashrc` is only read by non-login, interactive shells. AFAIK, `sudo` starts a [non-interactive shell](http://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) so none of the regular startup files will be read.  iii) there must have been a syntax error then. It worked fine on my machine. iv) I'm not surprised. My original solution overwrote anything in `LD_PRELOAD` and, as I mentioned, that could cause problems. Sadly, `/etc/environment` only takes simple `foo=bar` assignments so there was no other choice.