# 16.04 ssh exits immediately

Tags: 16.04, bash, ssh, dell

I have new brand new Dell with Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS pre-installed.  I've done updates, setup a local account and installed ssh.

When I try to ssh into the machine it asks for my password, prints "Welcome to Ubuntu", "last login: Thu..." and then "Connection closed".

This happens from remote systems, or locally when I run

```
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

The problem is just login sessions, it works if I give it a command like

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 /bin/date
```

I can even get a minimally working shell but it isn't attached to a tty so lots of things don't work.

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 /bin/bash -i
```

The account uses bash.  The startup scripts are unchanged from the ones in /etc/skel, just .bashrc and .profile.  I've tried moving them aside.  Based on an old answer I have verified that they don't have an exit in them.

I'm using a normal user account; not root.

Comment: Try `ssh -t 127.0.0.1 /bin/bash -i`. The `-t` asks for a TTY allocation.

Comment: For fun, grep your_username /etc/passwd  and see if anything is funky there.  Unless the VAR or you changed something, what you are trying to do should work swell.   Also, you could try ssh -l localhost using a different username.  If this works that would eliminate a lot of possibilities.  Lastly, after you ssh localhost, cat /HOME/.bash_history and see if there is an unexpected exit or quit at the end of it.

Comment: muru, thanks for the ssh -t tip.  It does successfully work around the current problem and would have been great to know countless times in my past when trying to login to partially wedged systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to isolate the problem by adding debugging statements to /etc/profile to trace early startup.

Dell has added a file /etc/profile.d/display-toggle-keybinding.sh to fiddle with some keybindings.  That file starts with:

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then  
   exit 0  
fi
```

Since things in /etc/profile.d are sourced, they run in the current shell rather that a subshell, so when they exit it kills off the whole session.

Once I saw the problem it was easily verified by trying

```
ssh -X 127.0.0.1
```

which worked fine.  The -X enables X11 forwarding which means that DISPLAY is set.  The problem only occurs when DISPLAY is not set.

You can correct the problem by editing /etc/profile.d/display-toggle-keybinding.sh and changing the "exit 0" to "return 0".  "return" is a slightly less powerful version of "exit" which only exits the file currently being executed.

The comment in the file indicates that it is from package "dell-wmi-aio" so it may be unique to AIO systems.  I'm using an Optiplex 7450 AIO.

I found the answer to this question to be very helpful in describing how the various types of bash shells (interactive, login, graphical etc) differ and what their startup sequences are:
[Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored)