# alias settings nor working at logon

Tags: bash, alias

Newly installed hirsute = 21.04. Installed out of the package, created my own personal account, the default .bashrc is present in my homedir and to make sure there is a .bash_aliases too. Both mention
`alias ll='ls -alF'`
still this alias is not available after logon. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"

karel@schal:~$ pwd ; ls -al .bash*
/home/karel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 karel users   53 Sep 26 06:22 .bash_aliases
-rw------- 1 karel users 9834 Sep 26 06:23 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 karel users 3771 Aug 31 23:17 .bashrc
karel@schal:~$ cat .bash_aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
karel@schal:~$ ll
ll: command not found
```

edited after a not-very-friendly comment, to add:

```
karel@wiske:~$ ssh karel@192.168.0.210
karel@192.168.0.210's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 21.04 (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-34-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.


The list of available updates is more than a week old.
To check for new updates run: sudo apt update
Last login: Sun Sep 26 09:37:21 2021
karel@schal:~$ alias
karel@schal:~$ /bin/bash
karel@schal:~$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

and that behaviour is identical, whether logging in per ssh or in the local graphical environment or on a local text-only console (dev/tty5 and similar)

Also, as requested, excerpt from ~/.bashrc:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

[further edited as requested]

```
karel@schal:~$ ls -al ~/.bash_profile  ~/.bash_login ./.profile
ls: cannot access '/home/karel/.bash_profile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/home/karel/.bash_login': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access './.profile': No such file or directory
karel@schal:~$ ps -p $$ | tail -n1 | awk '{print $NF}'
bash
```

Comment: You need to [include/source it from your `.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/5278/349837). Run `alias` to list all your available aliases

Comment: Thank you, Pablo. But that had been checked, and is only normal for the "vanilla" default installation. As for the "alias" command, it returns zero output.

Comment: Does it work [temporarily] to add an alias directly on the command line, for example `alias rm='rm -i'` ? Does it work [persistently] to add an alias into `~/.bashrc`, the next time you open a terminal window or text screen with `bash`?

Comment: Adding an alias from the command line works, yes. But whatever I tweak to .bashrc or .bash_aliases has zero effect. I am beginning to doubt whether .bashrc gets executed at all. Checked /var/log/syslog but found nothing relevant.

Comment: It seems you are you running some other shell program? What happens, if you start `bash` explicitly with the command line `bash` ?

Comment: Did you tweak any of the commands or configuration files, that might stop executing `~/.bashrc` ? Or is it possible that someone else tweaked the system to make that happen?

Comment: Please [edit] your questions and i) tell us what happens if you add an alias definition to your `~/.bashrc` and _not_ the non-standard `~/.bash_aliases`. Does that work? ii) show us the output of `echo $SHELL` and `ps aux -p $$` so we can see what shell you are running. iii) Clarify how you log in. Is this a local system or a remote one? Do you log in via the GUI or perhaps by ssh? Finally, don't tell us "it has been checked". Show us the actual line from your `~/.bashrc` that reads the `~/.bash_aliases` file since that is not a bash feature, and is an Ubuntu modification.

Comment: Something will be wrong earlier in your `.bashrc`. Check by moving it out (renaming it) then copying in the system default .bashrc (which indeed is set up to source .bash_aliases): cp /etc/skel/.bashrc .

Comment: It is also possible that you are not running bash but some other shell by default, for example csh, tcsh, zsh. Please check according to the commands in terdon's comment.

Comment: @vanadium: I looked into that, but to no avail. ```diff .\.bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc``` yielded zero output.

Comment: I assume you mean my comment when you say "a not-very-friendly comment". If so, sorry! I didn't mean to come across as brusque. If that's how it came across, I must have expressed myself badly. My apologies. For what it's worth, I had also upvoted your question since yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

When logging in over ssh, you are running what is known as an *interactive login shell*, and not an *interactive non-login shell* which is what happens when you open a terminal once logged in. Login shells do not read `~/.bashrc` and instead read `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`. This is why your aliases are not present. For more details on this and the differences between the initialization files of various shell types, see [Why are scripts in /etc/profile.d/ being ignored (system-wide bash aliases)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/438150/85695). This is also why you do get your aliases when you run `/bin/bash` since that starts a non-login shell and will read `~/.bashrc`.

That said, Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` file includes these lines:

```sh
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

So it should actually be reading your `~/.bashrc` as well. If this isn't happening, I suspect one of the following:

1. You (or someone) have created a `~/.bash_profile` file. That would cause the `~/.profile` file to be ignored. As explained in `man bash` (emphasis mine):

   > When bash is invoked as an interactive login  shell,  or
   > as  a  non-interactive shell with the --login option, it
   > first  reads  and  executes  commands  from   the   file
   > /etc/profile,  if  that file exists.  After reading that
   > file, **it looks for ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and
   > ~/.profile,  in  that order, and reads and executes com‐
   > mands from the first one that exists  and  is  readable**.
   > The  --noprofile  option  may  be used when the shell is
   > started to inhibit this behavior.

   So if either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exist, then anything in `~/.profile` is ignored.
2. You (or someone else) have created your own `~/.profile` which does not source `~/.bashrc`.
3. You are not actually running `bash`. You can check this by running `ps -p $$ | tail -n1 | awk '{print $NF}'` in the shell where you don't have aliases. If the output isn't `bash`, you are running a different shell. Perhaps you've set your default login shell to `sh`, which is `dash` on Ubuntu. You can check the current value with `echo $SHELL` and you can change it with `chsh`.

---

Based on your latest edit, it seems that your case is:

4. You don't have a `~/.profile` for some reason. And, based on your last edit, this seems to be the case. So just copy the default `.profile` from `/etc/skel` and you should be fine next time you log in:

   ```
   cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
   ```

Answer (score 1):

@terdon had it right: for some reason or other, there was no .profile in my homedir. All was okay after - as suggested -
`cp /etc/skel/.profile ~`