# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: surrogates not allowed

Tags: command-line, bash, python, aws

I have written a small code snippet to check the aws cli version

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e "/usr/local/bin/aws" ];
then
    myAWS="/usr/local/bin/aws"
else
    myAWS="/usr/bin/aws"
fi

myCmd=("${myAWS} --version")

echo "$myCmd"

message=$($myCmd)

echo "$message"
```

Now while running this manually with root user I am able to run but after our aws cli upgrade  while running this via crontab

```
57 21 * * * /rough/scripts/log/test.sh > /rough/scripts/log/test.log 2>&1
```

I face the below error , can you suggest , i have reinstalled the aws cli but to no effect.

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/core.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/io.py", line 43, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: surrogates not allowed
[24036] Failed to execute script 'aws' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: `cron` runtime environment is different. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script/673918#673918

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, is there a way I can check the current crontab runtime enviroment ?

Comment: Is it possible that an aws configuration file in your profile (~/.aws/config, ~/.aws/credentials etc.) has a non UTF-8 encoding and your local environment handles that by setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` for example?

Comment: hi @steeldriver- I checked the  ./aws/config file ----cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
region=eu-west-1  I am confused that if i run the script manually it runs fine but crontab is giving me the problem, any suggestions that can help surpass this error

Comment: May I ask what the point of the script is? I mean, why bother having the `if` to check two directories that are already in your `$PATH`? The whole script looks like it can be simplified to just the single command `aws --version`. Is it that you want to always prioritize the version found in `/usr/local/bin/` even if there is another in `/usr/bin/`? And why do `message=$(command); echo $message` instead of simply just running `command` directly?

Answer (score 0):

[Cron has its own `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/22222) which is hardcoded in the source code. This means that cron commands will run in a different environment. My guess is that your user (or root) are configured with a different `python` in their `PATH`. Or maybe you activate a python environment on login, or have installed some `pip` packages. Whatever the case may be, you will need to reproduce that in your `cron`.

First, run `echo "$PATH"` while logged in as the user for whom the command works. Then, take the `PATH` that prints and add it to the beginning of the crontab:

```
PATH="blah;blah;blah"
57 21 * * * /rough/scripts/log/test.sh > /rough/scripts/log/test.log 2>&1
```

If that doesn't work, you can try loading the user's shell configuration file with `bash -i`:

```
       -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

That will force `bash` to run in "interactive" mode, meaning it will read the invoking user's `~/.bashrc` file (see https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695):

```
57 21 * * * bash -i /rough/scripts/log/test.sh > /rough/scripts/log/test.log 2>&1
```

If that still doesn't work, you will need to figure out exactly what python setup you are using and where it comes from and try to reproduce that in the crontab. If you edit your question with more detail about your setup we might be able to help.

---

On an unrelated note, you could simplify your script a little. First, since both `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in the default `PATH`, if the objective of your `if` is to find which of the two contains an `aws` executable, then you don't need the `if` at all and can simply run `aws`.

If instead you want to always prioritize the version in `/usr/local/bin` even if there is another one in `/usr/bin`, then the `if` makes sense.

Next, there's not much point in running `message=$(command); echo $message`: if `command` prints out what you want to see, just run it directly. I would write your script like this instead:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
myAws=/usr/bin/aws
[ -e /usr/local/bin/aws ] && myAws=/usr/local/bin/aws

myCmd=("$myAWS" "--version")
echo "${myCmd[@]}"
"${myCmd[@]}"
```

Or, if you just want to run *an* `aws` and the `if` was only to figure out where it is installed, and you also want to see the full  path to it, simply:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
myAws=$(which aws)
myCmd=("$myAws" "--version")
echo "${myCmd[@]}"
"${myCmd[@]}"
```